# undestanding feed_dict in sess.run

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow.  I have some code I'm trying to understand.  Is there a way to get a list of all possible inputs for the "feed_dict" in sess.run?  Is the structure of feed_dict always the same or does it depend on the session?

code:

```
sess.run([input,input2],feed_dict={is_train:False,y:stuff,user:[_user]})
```

Update:

Code below from comments describing how to get input for feed_dict

Code:

```
# populate session graph to look at place holders
# place holders are possible inputs to sess.run()

for op in sess.graph.get_operations():
     print(op.name, op.type)
```

Output:

```
(u'Placeholder', u'Placeholder')
(u'ToFloat', u'Cast')
(u'sub/y', u'Const')
(u'sub', u'Sub')
(u'div/y', u'Const')
(u'div', u'RealDiv')
(u'Placeholder_1', u'Placeholder')
(u'DVBPR/Reshape/shape', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/Reshape', u'Reshape')
(u'DVBPR/wc1/Initializer/random_uniform/shape', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wc1/Initializer/random_uniform/min', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wc1/Initializer/random_uniform/max', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wc1/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform', u'RandomUniform')
(u'DVBPR/wc1/Initializer/random_uniform/sub', u'Sub')
(u'DVBPR/wc1/Initializer/random_uniform/mul', u'Mul')
(u'DVBPR/wc1/Initializer/random_uniform', u'Add')
(u'DVBPR/wc1', u'VariableV2')
(u'DVBPR/wc1/Assign', u'Assign')
(u'DVBPR/wc1/read', u'Identity')
(u'DVBPR/zeros', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/bc1', u'VariableV2')
(u'DVBPR/bc1/Assign', u'Assign')
(u'DVBPR/bc1/read', u'Identity')
(u'DVBPR/Conv2D', u'Conv2D')
(u'DVBPR/BiasAdd', u'BiasAdd')
(u'DVBPR/Relu', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR/Relu_1', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR/MaxPool', u'MaxPool')
(u'DVBPR/wc2/Initializer/random_uniform/shape', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wc2/Initializer/random_uniform/min', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wc2/Initializer/random_uniform/max', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wc2/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform', u'RandomUniform')
(u'DVBPR/wc2/Initializer/random_uniform/sub', u'Sub')
(u'DVBPR/wc2/Initializer/random_uniform/mul', u'Mul')
(u'DVBPR/wc2/Initializer/random_uniform', u'Add')
(u'DVBPR/wc2', u'VariableV2')
(u'DVBPR/wc2/Assign', u'Assign')
(u'DVBPR/wc2/read', u'Identity')
(u'DVBPR/zeros_1', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/bc2', u'VariableV2')
(u'DVBPR/bc2/Assign', u'Assign')
(u'DVBPR/bc2/read', u'Identity')
(u'DVBPR/Conv2D_1', u'Conv2D')
(u'DVBPR/BiasAdd_1', u'BiasAdd')
(u'DVBPR/Relu_2', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR/Relu_3', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR/MaxPool_1', u'MaxPool')
(u'DVBPR/wc3/Initializer/random_uniform/shape', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wc3/Initializer/random_uniform/min', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wc3/Initializer/random_uniform/max', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wc3/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform', u'RandomUniform')
(u'DVBPR/wc3/Initializer/random_uniform/sub', u'Sub')
(u'DVBPR/wc3/Initializer/random_uniform/mul', u'Mul')
(u'DVBPR/wc3/Initializer/random_uniform', u'Add')
(u'DVBPR/wc3', u'VariableV2')
(u'DVBPR/wc3/Assign', u'Assign')
(u'DVBPR/wc3/read', u'Identity')
(u'DVBPR/zeros_2', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/bc3', u'VariableV2')
(u'DVBPR/bc3/Assign', u'Assign')
(u'DVBPR/bc3/read', u'Identity')
(u'DVBPR/Conv2D_2', u'Conv2D')
(u'DVBPR/BiasAdd_2', u'BiasAdd')
(u'DVBPR/Relu_4', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR/Relu_5', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR/wc4/Initializer/random_uniform/shape', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wc4/Initializer/random_uniform/min', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wc4/Initializer/random_uniform/max', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wc4/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform', u'RandomUniform')
(u'DVBPR/wc4/Initializer/random_uniform/sub', u'Sub')
(u'DVBPR/wc4/Initializer/random_uniform/mul', u'Mul')
(u'DVBPR/wc4/Initializer/random_uniform', u'Add')
(u'DVBPR/wc4', u'VariableV2')
(u'DVBPR/wc4/Assign', u'Assign')
(u'DVBPR/wc4/read', u'Identity')
(u'DVBPR/zeros_3', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/bc4', u'VariableV2')
(u'DVBPR/bc4/Assign', u'Assign')
(u'DVBPR/bc4/read', u'Identity')
(u'DVBPR/Conv2D_3', u'Conv2D')
(u'DVBPR/BiasAdd_3', u'BiasAdd')
(u'DVBPR/Relu_6', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR/Relu_7', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR/wc5/Initializer/random_uniform/shape', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wc5/Initializer/random_uniform/min', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wc5/Initializer/random_uniform/max', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wc5/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform', u'RandomUniform')
(u'DVBPR/wc5/Initializer/random_uniform/sub', u'Sub')
(u'DVBPR/wc5/Initializer/random_uniform/mul', u'Mul')
(u'DVBPR/wc5/Initializer/random_uniform', u'Add')
(u'DVBPR/wc5', u'VariableV2')
(u'DVBPR/wc5/Assign', u'Assign')
(u'DVBPR/wc5/read', u'Identity')
(u'DVBPR/zeros_4', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/bc5', u'VariableV2')
(u'DVBPR/bc5/Assign', u'Assign')
(u'DVBPR/bc5/read', u'Identity')
(u'DVBPR/Conv2D_4', u'Conv2D')
(u'DVBPR/BiasAdd_4', u'BiasAdd')
(u'DVBPR/Relu_8', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR/Relu_9', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR/MaxPool_2', u'MaxPool')
(u'DVBPR/Reshape_1/shape', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/Reshape_1', u'Reshape')
(u'DVBPR/wd1/Initializer/random_uniform/shape', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wd1/Initializer/random_uniform/min', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wd1/Initializer/random_uniform/max', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wd1/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform', u'RandomUniform')
(u'DVBPR/wd1/Initializer/random_uniform/sub', u'Sub')
(u'DVBPR/wd1/Initializer/random_uniform/mul', u'Mul')
(u'DVBPR/wd1/Initializer/random_uniform', u'Add')
(u'DVBPR/wd1', u'VariableV2')
(u'DVBPR/wd1/Assign', u'Assign')
(u'DVBPR/wd1/read', u'Identity')
(u'DVBPR/MatMul', u'MatMul')
(u'DVBPR/zeros_5/shape_as_tensor', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/zeros_5/Const', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/zeros_5', u'Fill')
(u'DVBPR/bd1', u'VariableV2')
(u'DVBPR/bd1/Assign', u'Assign')
(u'DVBPR/bd1/read', u'Identity')
(u'DVBPR/Add', u'Add')
(u'DVBPR/Relu_10', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR/dropout/keep_prob', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wd2/Initializer/random_uniform/shape', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wd2/Initializer/random_uniform/min', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wd2/Initializer/random_uniform/max', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wd2/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform', u'RandomUniform')
(u'DVBPR/wd2/Initializer/random_uniform/sub', u'Sub')
(u'DVBPR/wd2/Initializer/random_uniform/mul', u'Mul')
(u'DVBPR/wd2/Initializer/random_uniform', u'Add')
(u'DVBPR/wd2', u'VariableV2')
(u'DVBPR/wd2/Assign', u'Assign')
(u'DVBPR/wd2/read', u'Identity')
(u'DVBPR/MatMul_1', u'MatMul')
(u'DVBPR/zeros_6/shape_as_tensor', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/zeros_6/Const', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/zeros_6', u'Fill')
(u'DVBPR/bd2', u'VariableV2')
(u'DVBPR/bd2/Assign', u'Assign')
(u'DVBPR/bd2/read', u'Identity')
(u'DVBPR/Add_1', u'Add')
(u'DVBPR/Relu_11', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR/dropout_1/keep_prob', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wd3/Initializer/random_uniform/shape', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wd3/Initializer/random_uniform/min', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wd3/Initializer/random_uniform/max', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/wd3/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform', u'RandomUniform')
(u'DVBPR/wd3/Initializer/random_uniform/sub', u'Sub')
(u'DVBPR/wd3/Initializer/random_uniform/mul', u'Mul')
(u'DVBPR/wd3/Initializer/random_uniform', u'Add')
(u'DVBPR/wd3', u'VariableV2')
(u'DVBPR/wd3/Assign', u'Assign')
(u'DVBPR/wd3/read', u'Identity')
(u'DVBPR/MatMul_2', u'MatMul')
(u'DVBPR/zeros_7', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/bd3', u'VariableV2')
(u'DVBPR/bd3/Assign', u'Assign')
(u'DVBPR/bd3/read', u'Identity')
(u'DVBPR/Add_2', u'Add')
(u'DVBPR/random_uniform/shape', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/random_uniform/min', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/random_uniform/max', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/random_uniform/RandomUniform', u'RandomUniform')
(u'DVBPR/random_uniform/sub', u'Sub')
(u'DVBPR/random_uniform/mul', u'Mul')
(u'DVBPR/random_uniform', u'Add')
(u'DVBPR/div/y', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR/div', u'RealDiv')
(u'DVBPR/Variable', u'VariableV2')
(u'DVBPR/Variable/Assign', u'Assign')
(u'DVBPR/Variable/read', u'Identity')
(u'init', u'NoOp')
(u'save/Const', u'Const')
(u'save/SaveV2/tensor_names', u'Const')
(u'save/SaveV2/shape_and_slices', u'Const')
(u'save/SaveV2', u'SaveV2')
(u'save/control_dependency', u'Identity')
(u'save/RestoreV2/tensor_names', u'Const')
(u'save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices', u'Const')
(u'save/RestoreV2', u'RestoreV2')
(u'save/Assign', u'Assign')
(u'save/Assign_1', u'Assign')
(u'save/Assign_2', u'Assign')
(u'save/Assign_3', u'Assign')
(u'save/Assign_4', u'Assign')
(u'save/Assign_5', u'Assign')
(u'save/Assign_6', u'Assign')
(u'save/Assign_7', u'Assign')
(u'save/Assign_8', u'Assign')
(u'save/Assign_9', u'Assign')
(u'save/Assign_10', u'Assign')
(u'save/Assign_11', u'Assign')
(u'save/Assign_12', u'Assign')
(u'save/Assign_13', u'Assign')
(u'save/Assign_14', u'Assign')
(u'save/Assign_15', u'Assign')
(u'save/Assign_16', u'Assign')
(u'save/restore_all', u'NoOp')
(u'Reshape/tensor', u'Const')
(u'Reshape/shape', u'Const')
(u'Reshape', u'Reshape')
(u'input_code/initial_value', u'Const')
(u'input_code', u'VariableV2')
(u'input_code/Assign', u'Assign')
(u'input_code/read', u'Identity')
(u'Placeholder_2', u'Placeholder')
(u'ResizeNearestNeighbor/size', u'Const')
(u'ResizeNearestNeighbor', u'ResizeNearestNeighbor')
(u'DVBPR_1/Reshape/shape', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR_1/Reshape', u'Reshape')
(u'DVBPR_1/zeros', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR_1/Conv2D', u'Conv2D')
(u'DVBPR_1/BiasAdd', u'BiasAdd')
(u'DVBPR_1/Relu', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR_1/Relu_1', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR_1/MaxPool', u'MaxPool')
(u'DVBPR_1/zeros_1', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR_1/Conv2D_1', u'Conv2D')
(u'DVBPR_1/BiasAdd_1', u'BiasAdd')
(u'DVBPR_1/Relu_2', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR_1/Relu_3', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR_1/MaxPool_1', u'MaxPool')
(u'DVBPR_1/zeros_2', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR_1/Conv2D_2', u'Conv2D')
(u'DVBPR_1/BiasAdd_2', u'BiasAdd')
(u'DVBPR_1/Relu_4', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR_1/Relu_5', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR_1/zeros_3', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR_1/Conv2D_3', u'Conv2D')
(u'DVBPR_1/BiasAdd_3', u'BiasAdd')
(u'DVBPR_1/Relu_6', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR_1/Relu_7', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR_1/zeros_4', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR_1/Conv2D_4', u'Conv2D')
(u'DVBPR_1/BiasAdd_4', u'BiasAdd')
(u'DVBPR_1/Relu_8', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR_1/Relu_9', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR_1/MaxPool_2', u'MaxPool')
(u'DVBPR_1/Reshape_1/shape', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR_1/Reshape_1', u'Reshape')
(u'DVBPR_1/MatMul', u'MatMul')
(u'DVBPR_1/zeros_5/shape_as_tensor', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR_1/zeros_5/Const', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR_1/zeros_5', u'Fill')
(u'DVBPR_1/Add', u'Add')
(u'DVBPR_1/Relu_10', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR_1/dropout/keep_prob', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR_1/MatMul_1', u'MatMul')
(u'DVBPR_1/zeros_6/shape_as_tensor', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR_1/zeros_6/Const', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR_1/zeros_6', u'Fill')
(u'DVBPR_1/Add_1', u'Add')
(u'DVBPR_1/Relu_11', u'Relu')
(u'DVBPR_1/dropout_1/keep_prob', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR_1/MatMul_2', u'MatMul')
(u'DVBPR_1/zeros_7', u'Const')
(u'DVBPR_1/Add_2', u'Add')
(u'Placeholder_3', u'Placeholder')
(u'GatherV2/axis', u'Const')
(u'GatherV2', u'GatherV2')
(u'transpose/Rank', u'Rank')
(u'transpose/sub/y', u'Const')
(u'transpose/sub', u'Sub')
(u'transpose/Range/start', u'Const')
(u'transpose/Range/delta', u'Const')
(u'transpose/Range', u'Range')
(u'transpose/sub_1', u'Sub')
(u'transpose', u'Transpose')
(u'MatMul', u'MatMul')
(u'Sum/reduction_indices', u'Const')
(u'Sum', u'Sum')
```

Code:

```
# get all placeholders in graph

placeholders = [ op for op in sess.graph.get_operations() if op.type == "Placeholder"]

placeholders
```

Output:

```
[<tf.Operation 'Placeholder' type=Placeholder>,
 <tf.Operation 'Placeholder_1' type=Placeholder>,
 <tf.Operation 'Placeholder_2' type=Placeholder>,
 <tf.Operation 'Placeholder_3' type=Placeholder>]
```

Update 2:

from main.py in DVBPR folder at https://github.com/kang205/DVBPR

```
#define model
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    #training sample
    queueu = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32,shape=[1])
    queuei = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32,shape=[1])
    queuej = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32,shape=[1])
    queueimage1 = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.uint8,shape=[224,224,3])
    queueimage2 = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.uint8,shape=[224,224,3])
    batch_train_queue = tf.FIFOQueue(batch_size*5, dtypes=[tf.int32,tf.int32,tf.int32,tf.uint8,tf.uint8], shapes=[[1],[1],[1],[224,224,3],[224,224,3]])
    batch_train_queue_op = batch_train_queue.enqueue([queueu,queuei,queuej,queueimage1,queueimage2]);
    u,i,j,image1,image2 = batch_train_queue.dequeue_many(batch_size)

    image_test=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.uint8,shape=[batch_size,224,224,3])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Good questions. First, `feed_dict` is simply a python [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in which each key is a [`tf.placeholder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder) and each corresponding value is a python object. This object must have a shape equal to that of the corresponding placeholder, and must have a datatype which can be coerced into the placeholders `dtype`. The structure of `feed_dict` is dictated by the structure of the graph, because there must be one dictionary key-value tuple for each placeholder in the graph.

To get all of the placeholders in the graph, the following one-liner will do:

```
placeholders = [ op for op in graph.get_operations() if op.type == "Placeholder"]
```

Credit for that solution goes to [this comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14374#issuecomment-377076635) on a related TensorFlow issue. This one-liner works by reviewing each operation and appending it to `placeholders` if the operation type is `"Placeholder"`.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, that was extremely helpful.  Especially when combined with the previous comment.  As I asked above, do the placeholders get a number added to their name automatically if the name "Placeholder" is repeated in the code?  I have a few placeholders named like "Placeholder_1" but I don't have anything in my code named "Placeholder_1".

Answer (score 3):

feed_dict is just a dictionary where the key is the variable containing tensor information, and the value is the data to be fed to the network. Usually you can populate the session graph and find the placeholders, as they can only be inputs to a graph. You can populate the graph by:

`for op in sess.graph.get_operations():
     print(op.name, op.type)`

As each session can depend on a different graph, feed_dict can have different inputs. If you are defining your own graph, it is good practice to keep the input placeholders as different variables.

Also your `sess.run` command is extracting inputs from the session.

Comment: @AbhishekShgal Thank you for getting back to me, that was extremely helpful.  Especially when combined with the next comment.  I was wondering do the placeholders get an number added to their name automatically if the name "Placeholder" is repeated in the code?  I seem to have a few placeholders named like "Placeholder_1" but I don't have anything in my code named "Placeholder_1".

Comment: Are you using Jupyter Notebook? `_1` or other numbers are added to the name of the Layer when the same name layer has been declared again. I can see `Placeholder_1` as the 7th operation in your graph. To avoid confusion, you can declare the name argument while declaring the layer.

Comment: Thank you again, yes I am running it in a jupyter notebook.  The original code comes from this repo https://github.com/kang205/DVBPR.  I've taken the main.py file that's in the DVBPR folder and broken it up in to cells in a jupyter notebook to run it a piece at a time and understand the code better.  In the define model section of main.py there are several lines that use tf.placeholder, and they're all declared like "queueu = tf.placeholder(...)" .  So why are there only 4 inputs  and why do they have names like placeholder_1?  Is it because I'm running it in jupyter?

Comment: I added an update to the original post with the code from main.py using tf.placeholder.

Comment: So according to your code, as you create a `tf.placeholder` without a name tag, tensorflow will automatically give it a name and if you create a new one add `_1` and so on. Try changing the code as `queueu = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32,shape=[1], name="queueu")` and so on. The name of your placeholders will now be what you want them to be. You can also check this by executing `queueu.op`